# Cannot find symbol - NETBEANS

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

Eu estava programando, até ai tudo bem, porem quando 'getar' +txt_endereco.getText()+ dá cannot find symbol, quando vou 'setar' acontace a mesma coisa 'txt_endereco.setText(model.getValueAt(indexrow, 4).toString()); '
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Codigo:

```
    /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package controleescolar;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class detalhesescolares extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form detalhesescolares
     */
    public detalhesescolares() {
        initComponents();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getdata();
        chk();
    }

    String host="jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/Controle Escolar";
        String usuario="root";
        String senha="admin";
        private void chk()
        {
            try
    {
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(host, usuario, senha);
            Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
            String querry="select * from DetalhesEscolares";
            ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(querry);
            if(!rs.next())
            {
                txt_botao1.setEnabled(false);
            }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!"+e);
    }
        }

    private void getdata()
    {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)txt_tabela.getModel();
        model.setRowCount(0);
        try
        {
                Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(host, usuario, senha);
                Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
                String query="select * from DetalhesEscolares";
                ResultSet rs= stmt.executeQuery(query);
                while(!rs.next())
                {
                    model.addRow(new Object[]{rs.getInt("id"),rs.getString("nome"),rs.getString("telefone"),rs.getString("email"),rs.getString("endereco"),rs.getString("site")});
                }    

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {    
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!"+e);    
        }    
    }        

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        txt_tabela = new javax.swing.JTable();
        txt_site = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txt_nome = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txt_tell = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txt_email = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jLabel4 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel5 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel6 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        txt_botao1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txt_botao2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txt_botao3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        txt_endereco = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        txt_tabela.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
            new Object [][] {
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null},
                {null, null, null, null, null}
            },
            new String [] {
                "NOME", "TELEFONE", "EMAIL", "ENDEREÇO", "SITE"
            }
        ));
        txt_tabela.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
            public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
                txt_tabelaMouseClicked(evt);
            }
        });
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(txt_tabela);

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("Nome:");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Telefone:");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Email:");

        jLabel4.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel4.setText("Site:");

        jLabel5.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel5.setText("Endereço:");

        jLabel6.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 36)); // NOI18N
        jLabel6.setText("Detalhes Escolares");

        txt_botao1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        txt_botao1.setText("CRIAR");
        txt_botao1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txt_botao1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txt_botao2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        txt_botao2.setText("ATUALIZAR");
        txt_botao2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txt_botao2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        txt_botao3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        txt_botao3.setText("FECHAR");
        txt_botao3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                txt_botao3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                            .addComponent(jScrollPane1)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                            .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                            .addComponent(txt_nome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 236, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(txt_tell, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                            .addComponent(txt_email, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel5))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(83, 83, 83)
                                        .addComponent(txt_botao1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(40, 40, 40)
                                        .addComponent(txt_botao2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel4)))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGap(0, 42, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                        .addComponent(txt_botao3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 150, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addGap(80, 80, 80))
                                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                                            .addComponent(txt_site, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 270, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                            .addComponent(txt_endereco))
                                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE))))))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(183, 183, 183)
                        .addComponent(jLabel6)
                        .addGap(0, 0, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jLabel6)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(txt_endereco)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(txt_nome, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel5))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(txt_tell, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel2))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(txt_email, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(txt_site, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addComponent(jLabel4))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 21, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                        .addComponent(txt_botao2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(txt_botao3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addComponent(txt_botao1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 229, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void txt_botao1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        try{
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(host,usuario,senha);
            Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
            String query="insert into DetalhesEscolares (nome,telefone,email,endereco,site) values('"+txt_nome.getText()+"','"+txt_tell.getText()+"','"+txt_email.getText()+"','"+txt_endereco.getText()+"','"+txt_site.getText()+"') ";
            stmt.execute(query);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Salvo!");
getdata();
vazio();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error!"+e);
    }
    }                                          
String id;
    private void txt_tabelaMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:        // TODO add your handling code here:
        int indexrow= txt_tabela.getSelectedRow();

        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)txt_tabela.getModel();
        id=model.getValueAt(indexrow, 0).toString();
        txt_nome.setText(model.getValueAt(indexrow, 1).toString());
        txt_tell.setText(model.getValueAt(indexrow, 2).toString());
        txt_email.setText(model.getValueAt(indexrow, 3).toString());
        txt_endereco.setText(model.getValueAt(indexrow, 4).toString()); 
       txt_site.setText(model.getValueAt(indexrow, 5).toString());

    }                                       

    private void txt_botao2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        if(id!=null)
        {


        try{
            Connection con= DriverManager.getConnection(host,usuario,senha);
            Statement stmt= con.createStatement();
            String query="update DetalhesEscolares set nome='"+txt_nome.getText()+"',telefone='"+txt_tell.getText()+"',email='"+txt_email.getText()+"',endereco='"+txt_endereco.getText()+"',site='"+txt_site.getText()+"' where id="+id+" ";
            stmt.execute(query);
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Atualizado!");
getdata();
vazio();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione um item para atualizar!");
    }    
        }
        else
        {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Selecione um item para atualizar!");
        }    
    }                                          

    private void txt_botao3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        this.dispose();
    }                                          

    private void vazio()
    {
        id=null;
        txt_nome.setText(null);
        txt_tell.setText(null);
        txt_email.setText(null);
        txt_endereco.setText(null);
        txt_site.setText(null);
    }        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(detalhesescolares.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(detalhesescolares.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(detalhesescolares.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(detalhesescolares.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new detalhesescolares().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel4;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel5;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel6;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JButton txt_botao1;
    private javax.swing.JButton txt_botao2;
    private javax.swing.JButton txt_botao3;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txt_email;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane txt_endereco;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txt_nome;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txt_site;
    private javax.swing.JTable txt_tabela;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txt_tell;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: resolvido, mudei para texbox e consegui pegar a entrada e saida

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boa noite, `txt_endereco = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();` é um ScrollPane?? não deveria ser `javax.swing.JTextField();` como nos outros campos? `txt_nome = new javax.swing.JTextField();`